# How to print several Lists at once in Java?

Tags: java, printing, arraylist

Need help please, can't figure this out :(

I have the following ArrayLists:

- `List <String> schoolsList`
- `List <String> degreesList`
- `List <String> fieldsOfStudyList`
- `List <String> yearsFromList`
- `List <String> yearsToList`

How can I print them out in Java, so that the structure is following:

```
School
Degree, Field of study
Year attended from - Year attended to
```

Considering, there could be several of these blocks (in case the person have finnished several schools).

Comment: Why not use a class?

Comment: +1 for @MarcoAcierno.. this is what OOP is.

Comment: Which class? Sorry, i'm a newbie, could you tell more please? @MarcoAcierno

Comment: Read  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: The suggestion is to wrap all values (school, degree, field, yearFrom, yearTo) in a single class and then maintain a single `List<MyClass>`. Having multiple lists where all values are associated based on index in an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @JohnB. I'm gonna work on it, sorry for my question :(

Comment: No need to apologize.  Welcome to SO. FYI, it is good practice to accept the correct answer. I would suggest accepting azurefrog's answer. This gives (him/her) credit and closes the question so others know it is addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class, like `DegreeInfo` and make it have a field for each piece of data you care about:

```
public class DegreeInfo {
    String school;
    String degree;
    // etc
```

Then write a method on that class which prints the information in the format you need:

```
public void printDegreeInfo() {
    // nicely formatted printing here
}
```

Then you can have a `List<DegreeInfo>` instead a handful of disparate lists.